# Save Apache files under /var/www as www-data with inherited permissions

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I know this question has been asked and answered in various ways, but my searching has not produced an answer that seems to work for me, so I will ask specifically to my needs:

Running: Ubuntu 18.04, Apache2

I am trying to make it so that I **SFTP** in as my sudo user (Assume **johndoe** for user name) and create files and folders anywhere under **/var/www**, the following happens:

1. All files & folders I create AUTOMATICALLY have 775 permissions
2. All files are owned AUTOMATICALLY by www-data (and naturally in www-data group)
3. Anything I create under the /var/www directory inherits this behavior.

If someone can give me a step by step (rather than "just do this", that would be awesome, and I believe this would be a great answer for others.

If you have an argument for different permissions, please let me know.  What matters is that the web server can read and write files, and my SFTP user can as well.  What matters is that the permissions are correct when I create a new file uploaded by my SFTP user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For security you shouldn't make apache the owner of any files in the /var/www folder. You should create a seperate new user (with no shell) for each web app you store in the www-data folder and assign that new user as owner for all files and folders associated with that particular web app. In this way if Apache is compromised all your web apps and associated files are not compromised simultaneously.

Assign www-data as the group for files and sub-folders in /var/www , so that Apache can read and serve your web apps.

Give www-data read and execute permissions permissions for folders, only give www-data read permissions for files. In this way if Apache is compromised none of your files can not be modified by Apache.

```
//web app 1, set owner and group, do not set www-data as owner !
sudo chown -R web-app-1:www-data /var/www/app1

//web app 1, set appropriate permissions for all sub-folders as detailed previously 
sudo find /var/www/app1  -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;

//web app 1, set appropriate permissions for all files in sub-folders as detailed previously 
sudo find /var/www/html/app1  -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  While that is helpful for the sake of permissions, before I get to that point, I need to understand how to get files and folders to automatically have whatever permissions and ownership I want when they are created.

Comment: it quite simple, just run the above 3 commands any time you make changes

Comment: yes, but I am attempting to see if I can default all files and folders created by my user to those permissions as they are created.

Comment: use umask command for modifying default file and folder permissions

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that for whatever reason umask settings don't seem to persist between sessions with SFTP.  The only way I am finding that will work with persistent permissions on new files and folders is vsftp, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: if you can't get it to work just use the solution in my original answer, real simple...

Comment: I have tried every possible combination I can think of using chown, chgrp, chgrp and setfacl to put proper permissions in. Also, umask is 022.  Whatever I do, when I save a file through SFTP, it resets file permissions to 644, and I need a minimum 664 for my sudo user to save files with SFTP.  I am at a complete loss here :-(

Comment: What do you mean 664 for your sudo user to save files,  that does not make sense

Comment: OK, I should be more clear.  My user has sudo privs, and with SSH I have no probs. 
 But when I SFTP in and save a file, it sets the permissions to 644.  I can change the permissions after the fact (with SSH), but if I save it again with SFTP, it will reset to 644.  Of course, if I SSH in and sudo, I am acting as root.

Comment: Yes that is the permission defaults set by the operating system. That is what I would expect to happen. You should upload whether files then once you have finished uploading the files just run the 3 commands I gave to set owners and permissions as required.

Comment: And that is my problem.   So I completely get all of the security issues, but now say I am editing files on a site that is a remote dev server.  Each time I do a save of a file, those permissions get reset to 644.  Even though my user is part of the associated group for the folder (in this case www-data), 644 will not let me write the file since I am not the user 'www-data'.  running the chmod and chown commands on the directory makes perfect sense, but every single time I make a change to any file on a dev server is VERY laborious and time-intensive.

Comment: So what I asked in my original question still applies.  How can I make a change that give users of the group write access?  I have tried playing with umask and setfacl, but they do not appear to be persistent.

Comment: The unmask command only relates to permissions, you can not change the default owner of a file, whom ever created the file is the owner, so whatever route you take you will still have to enter commands to change the owner,  so my original answer still applies.

Comment: OK, that is fine.  The correct answer if this is the case would be "that is not possible".  Yes, I know how I can change owner and permissions after the fact.  The question was if I could make it default under some directories so that someone that is not the file (or folder) owner, but a member of the same group as the owner could have write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is possible, just that you will not make the edits directly to the folder, but to a mounted one in your /home/johndoe/websites folder which is actually the mounted /var/www/html folder. The owner of the edits/new files/etc will always be www-data user of www-data group.

*I have forgot how to do this, wanted to do it on a new server and could not find an answer on google. Searched for hours, ultimately I logged in on the server where I had this working and managed to find out how I was doing it*

So, follow this guide:
https://sammaye.wordpress.com/2018/08/09/use-bindfs-for-serving-ssh-users-with-web-server-access/

You might need to install bindfs, or fuse